Запретить масштабирование текста в react native
в системе есть возможность изменить мастштаб текста, вопрос: как отключить это масштабирование в приложение написанном на react native?

Для выполнения данной задачи я использовал стандартный метод из react-native - useWindowDimensions:
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native'

Далее в основной функции App я запросил размер масштабирования шрифта:
const fontScale = useWindowDimensions().fontScale;

И создал функцию для более удобного получения размера шрифта:
const tS = (fontSize) => {
    return (fontSize / fontScale)
}

После в стилях элементов вместо стилей:
{
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 50
}

Я указывал:
{
    fontSize: tS(18),
    lineHeight: tS(50)
}

